# AWS SDK upgrading to 2.4.0 the AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider is no longer available

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, aws-sdk-ios

I have update pod file with pod `'AWSiOSSDKv2'`.

There is `AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider` is deprecated in update version Of `AWSiOSSDKv2`. So my custom class for `IdentityProvider` is not working as previously. I am googling since last 2-3 day but still no any luck to find any alternative solution. Can anyone have alternative solution?